# How come I don't have to log in via RDP?

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop

I have 3 computers with 3 times the same username , but 3x different computer names.

- Rotterdam City Workstation
- Amsterdam City Workstation
- Mobile Laptop

I am visiting my parents in Amsterdam this week. Yesterday I connected from Amsterdam to my home workstation via RDP and I was surprised to see that I did not have to provide any login details. While I use the same full name on all computers, I do not use the same password on the workstations.

When I tried connecting with the laptop here via RDP to my home workstation in Rotterdam, it did ask me for the password. My laptop and the home workstation have the same password, the Amsterdam password is different. It would therefore be more logical if the laptop did not have to provide login information and the other workstation did.

There are no other users on all machines except for 1 Administrator called "my full name". All machines run Windows 7 x64.

Comment: How do you connect exactly? Haven't used RDP that much, but you can actually specify User/Password before even connecting, so maybe the credentials have been saved before?

Comment: You're sure you havn't connected to that machine before, and clicked to option to remember the username/password ?